# The permalinks in WordPress returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-404

I imported a wordpress production website into my local server to modify it and learn how to wordpress. I use LAMP and my WordPress project is located on a different Hard Drive than my Ubuntu 16.04 partition. But even if I can access to the main page, all the other links (except /wp-admin) are returning a 404 not found error.

As I could read, the problem could be that the .htaccess file was not read by apache2. To enable this option, I needed to enable the plugin rewrite with `sudo a2enmode rewrite` and to change in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` the :

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

by :

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If this may correct the error 404, it creates an internal server error...

Is anyone have an idea of how to handle this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: What's the internal error ?

Comment: Here it is !
https://zerobin.net/?1a4e6fe8aae7ae1c#GpqwLRcsA4y1EJhpCMG82pUfFPzAImvqjQJhEN4u8UU=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I needed to use the directory on my other HDD for every dev project, I changed the Server root of Apache2 and it resolves my problems

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed the rewrite rules yet?

Go to Settings -> Permalinks and hit save.

Alternatively, you can do it from your theme by calling the flush_rewrite_rules() function.

Comment: I did and it didn't solve my problem. But the links are working it's just like they send to a non published page (and they are all published). It doesn't even work when I click on the link on the editing page.
I really think, my problem is due to the fact that my project is not stored in `/var/www/html` but in an another HDD and linked to this directory with a symlink